# How do I recall a specific command from command history, without executing it

Tags: linux, bash

For example, in bash I can type `!xyz` which will run the last command I typed beginning with `xyz`.

How can I bring up the last command I typed beginning with `xyz` but without executing it?
e.g so I can change parameters before execution....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it like this: On the command prompt press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and then type the command you want to recall, in your case `xyz`. This will show you the complete command without executing it.

Comment: More useful than `!` notation, because you can press Ctrl-r multiple times to cycle further into matching history. When you arrive at the proper place, you can try to execute not with Enter but with Ctrl-o for much profit.

Answer (score 14):

Try `!xyz:p`; it will recall the command to the top of history without executing it, so eg up-arrow can immediately access it for interactive editing.

As an aside, I make a practice of doing this when recalling commands with a regexp that could conceivably dig up something damaging, ever since a hasty `!r`, intended to recall the most recent `rsync ...` command, pulled back **and executed** an `rm *` that had been pushed to the stack more recently than the rsync.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good practice. I have done the same with a `rm -rf ./*` never been so grateful for a period.   FYI The `!xyz:p` worked, thankyou, but required a few extra keystrokes than the ctrl-r solution.

Comment: @MtlDev yes; I find the ^R solution works best for `EMACS`ey folks, whereas the !-path works best for `vi`olators like me.

Comment: +1 for answering the question. Accepted answer suggests an alternative but I think `!` and Ctrl+r have different uses.

Comment: Also note, zsh's default behavior is not to execute when recalling with `!`. I was hoping bash would have a setting to make this its behavior as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Execute the following command. It will echo the last executed command. you can copy and edit the command. This command tested in debian.

   history |tail -2 | grep -v history | cut -d ' ' -f4-
2. Or Press and hold ctrl+R and type the starting letter of your last command. It will list the commands you executed previously based on your input. Once it shows desired command, just press right arrow in order to select that command.

Comment: The first command is so smooth !! I think it's faster to just look after the command in history than writing all of this ^__^

Answer (score 1):

If reverse history search failed, do anything of:

```
$ history | grep WHAT_YOU_LOOK_FOR
```

Or:

```
$ grep WHAT_YOU_LOOK_FOR ~/.bash_history
```